# Can I use ODAC 11g to access 10g

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I am developing an application with VS208 for different Oracle versions.  I am wondering if I need to install different version of ODAC to do this, or does the latest release has    backward compatibility?   Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [system requirements](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/install11106.html), it should work with 9i and up.  I've accessed a 10g database using 11g before without problem.  Although I should note that I didn't really do a whole lot with it.

Answer (score 1):

ODAC 11g will work (is backward compatible) with databases back to version 9.2. In general, unless you have a very compelling reason, it is a good idea to use the latest version if ODAC that you can to take advantages of bug fixes and new features.

Christian Shay

Oracle